# Can't recognize image using OCR

Tags: javascript, ocr, image-recognition

I was trying to use [ocrad.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js/) to convert an image to a string, but I didn't get the result string. I was also previewing the image, the problem is only in the image recognition.

This is my code:

```
function pr_image(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
        output.src = reader.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

    var stringletter = OCRAD(event.target.files[0]);
    document.getElementById('letter').value = stringletter;
}
```

and this is the browser's capture:

[unchanged value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK6md.png)

[no error message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5NHo.png)

I've tried to change the recognition code into this one function, but i get . as the image recognition's result:

```
function str_img(event) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    }

    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100);
    var stringletter = OCRAD(imageData);
    document.getElementById('letter').value = stringletter;
}
```

I suspect that I failed at converting the input file as image data. What should I do? Any help is appreciated!

Solved:

I've changed my code into this by Chris G and it works! Thank you

```
function preview_image(event) 
{
     var reader = new FileReader();
     var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
     reader.onload = function()
     {
        output.src = reader.result;
     }

     reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

     output.onload = function()
     {
        var stringletter = OCRAD(output);
        document.getElementById('letter').value = stringletter;
     }
}
```

Comment: Just like it's shown in the examples, you need to call `OCRAD()` inside the `onload` event handler. Otherwise the image isn't loaded yet and there's nothing to R.

Comment: I have called OCRAD() and change stringletter value inside reader.onload and img.onload function, but it's still not working.. Or should i add another onload function?I really appreciate your help, thank you

Comment: Please show your updated code, and make sure to pass `output` to `OCRAD()` (it accepts an `<Image>`/`Image`, Context2D or ImageData object)

Comment: turns out that i put the wrong code inside onload function. i changed my code into this and it works! Thank you very much!!

function preview_image(event) 
{
     var reader = new FileReader();
     var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
     reader.onload = function()
     {
        output.src = reader.result;
     }

     reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

     output.onload = function()
     {
        var stringletter = OCRAD(output);
        document.getElementById('letter').value = stringletter;
     }
}

Comment: Glad it works now, but I'd put those two lines into `reader.onload`. No need for a second callback.

Comment: It should be more simple to have one callback, but if I put it into reader.onload, an error occured. Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.

Comment: The code you added to your question doesn't use a canvas. Here's the code that worked for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nu627k49/